# Stored Procedure Parameters and Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports

I am creating a Stored Procedure that will be used as the Data Source for a Crystal Report.

The Stored Proc takes two input parameters - int and a comma delimited string list

```
 Create procedure sp_AP_YTD_Payments1
   @Year as int,
  @Companies nvarchar(MAX)

  as
       -- SP code here
```

I do realize that I will have to convert the string list to an array before using it in the where clause.

I have two questions :

1. How do I pass the parameters to the SP using an exec sp_AP_YTD_Payments1 ?
2. From Crystal Reports, how should the user enter the second argument ? As a comma delimited list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

1. exec sp_AP_YTD_Payments1 2013, '925,926,TXR'
2. From Crystal, the user will enter a comma-dlimited list for the Companies parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to handle the second parameter. If you are not using subreports you can move your report to a subreport, create a multivalued parameter in the main report and pass the parameter values to the subreport using Join function. This will allow your users to select the values from a list and to not care about the coma formatting.

This article for multivalued parameters in stored procedures might be helpful:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/MultivalueParametersWithSQLSP.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, I am not able to do this in Crystal 10.0. I can't get a list of values displayed that the user can select from

Comment: Parameter lists are available in version XI and above , for versions 10 and below you can consider using a viewer, which supports this feature. Check this video:http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_CascadingParameters.aspx It shows how to use this feature with Crystal 10 and bellow